# validateDelegate() in jquery.validate.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsp, passwords

Good day,

I am using a `js` where I get from https://gist.github.com/codesdk/e437415691949c7ffb9c

Inside this `js`, there is a method call `validateDelegate()`, and then inside this `validateDelegate()`, got something like :

```
validateDelegate(":text, [type='password'], [type='file']....
```

I am trying to find out how does this `validateDelegate()` work when my input type = password. But failed.

In my main jsp file, I have something like:

```
$.messages = {
        <%-- some other code--%>
        password: '<fmt:message key="errors.password" />',
        <%-- some other code--%>
    }
```

and I have a input field as follow:

```
<s:form beanclass="com.cv.ibs.cib.app.profile.ui.ChangePasswordAction"
    method="post">
<!-- some other jsp code -->
    <s:password name="changePassword.currentPassword" maxlength="30" size="45" autocomplete="off"/>
<!-- some other jsp code -->
        <sx:validations>
    </sx:validations>
</s:form>
```

So, every time I key in something in this password text box, and click/move to other space in the page, system will display error message beside this text box (client side validation), where the error message is control by key `errors.password`.

I am curious to know how is the `validateDelegate()` work to validate the input I key in. And what value should I key in to pass the validation.

Comment: can you share the generated html and script

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I already add in my html code. The script is actually download from https://gist.github.com/codesdk/e437415691949c7ffb9c